# A solution for a variation of N-Queen problem for N < 4 in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, n-queens

I need to resolve a variation of N-Queens as noted in [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html)

The maximum number of queens when N=2 or N=3 is N-1 queens, otherwise is N, so I need help to implement in Prolog for N<4.

For example for N=2:

```
?nqueens(2,Result).

Result = [2,empty]
Result = [empty,1]
Result = [empty,2]
Result = [1,empty]
```

which means 4 possible configurations in 2*2 table. The number in the list Result indicate the row and the position indicates the column.

For N=3:

```
?nqueens(3,Result).

Result = [1,3, empty]
Result = [1,empty,2]
Result = [3,1,empty]
Result = [empty,1,3]
Result = [2,empty,1]
Result = [empty,3,1]
Result = [2,empty,3]
Result = [3,empty,2]
```

8 possible configurations in 3*3 table.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/noiano/924ea01419a2dd03e0ba) is an standard solution for the variation of N-Queen problem (for N>=4), it does not work when N<4, and that is my problem.

Any help appreciated.

**EDITED (POSSIBLE SOLUTION)**
firstable i generate all combinations ,for N=2 would be like this:

```
permutInListN(List,N,Result) :- comb(N,List,Comb),permutation(Comb,Result).
comb(0,_,[]).
comb(N,[X|T],[X|Comb]) :-N>0,N1 is N-1,comb(N1,T,Comb).
comb(N,[_|T],Comb) :-N>0,comb(N,T,Comb).

?permutInListN([1,2,vacio],2,L).
%output
L = [1, 2]
L = [2, 1]
L = [1, empty]
L = [empty, 1]
L = [2, empty]
L = [empty, 2]
```

discard the listResul which no contains empty because when N=2 the posible queens is N-1(only 1 queen), the predicate for this using member and setoff..(is trivial), and the solution for this:

```
%output solution
L = [1, empty]
L = [empty, 1]
L = [2, empty]
L = [empty, 2]
```

Now for N=3 , thats the point , all ListResult for N=3:

```
?permutInListN([1,2,3,empty],3,L).
%output
L = [1, 2, 3]
L = [1, 3, 2]
L = [2, 1, 3]
L = [2, 3, 1]
L = [3, 1, 2]
L = [3, 2, 1]
L = [1, 2, empty]
L = [1, empty, 2]
L = [2, 1, empty]
L = [2, empty, 1]
L = [empty, 1, 2]
L = [empty, 2, 1]
L = [1, 3, empty]
L = [1, empty, 3]
L = [3, 1, empty]
L = [3, empty, 1]
L = [empty, 1, 3]
L = [empty, 3, 1]
L = [2, 3, empty]
L = [2, empty, 3]
L = [3, 2, empty]
L = [3, empty, 2]
L = [empty, 2, 3]
L = [empty, 3, 2]
```

discard the listResul which no contains empty, only 8 configurations for queens who no attack each other are valid from the output:

```
%output
L = [1, 2, empty]
L = [1, empty, 2]
L = [2, 1, empty]
L = [2, empty, 1]
L = [empty, 1, 2]
L = [empty, 2, 1]
L = [1, 3, empty]
L = [1, empty, 3]
L = [3, 1, empty]
L = [3, empty, 1]
L = [empty, 1, 3]
L = [empty, 3, 1]
L = [2, 3, empty]
L = [2, empty, 3]
L = [3, 2, empty]
L = [3, empty, 2]
L = [empty, 2, 3]
L = [empty, 3, 2]
```

for example L=[1,empty,2] and  L=[1,3,empty] those are valid ,and i thinking an algorithm which would be a possible solution:

> when is queen in first column and the other in 3rd column and there aren't a row between them its VALID
>   ex:L=[1,empty,2]---> [queen(first column,first row), queen(3rd column,2nd row),_]
>                          not row between them
>
> when is a queen follow of another queen in the next column and there are a row between them its VALID
>   ex:L=[1,3,empty] ----> [queen(first column,first row),queen(2nd column,3rd row),_]
>                          just a row between them

it works for the 8 configurations , any idea how to implement that ????????
i hope i have explained myself well.

Comment: There is *no* solution for the *n-queens* problem with *n=2* or *n=3*. For *n=1* there is a trivial solution: putting the queen on the only box.

Comment: i know, but it would be another version of the problem , thats what i need

Comment: Based on the sample output, it looks like one does not have to place *n* queens on the *n x n*-board. For the *n*-queens problem, that is however a requirement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

Comment: then you first will need to *define* exactly how that *other version* looks like.

Comment: just the same as the queen problem but working for this cases, i mean a variation of the known problem

Comment: [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html) notes another variation. `What is the maximum number of queens that can be placed on an n×n chessboard such that no two attack one another?`

Comment: yes, thats it , the max number of queens is n-1 , thats the reason in a 2*2 table the result is 1 queen only

Comment: I reformatted your question, and see a link to code. Is this your code? Also it appears to not work. Is your real question that you need help in fixing it?

Comment: no that's not my code is just a reference which works for the standard solution , i need help to resolve the problem for N<4 (Wolfram) , the code in link only works for N>=4.